# How to clip floated content

Tags: css, overflow, css-float

The following code snippet displays some headlines, with some icons floated on the left. The parent div has a defined height, with `scroll:auto` set.

Currently, scrolling to the bottom looks like this:

[image: before]

However, I'd like to clip off the icons when the text entries end, so when scrolling to the bottom, it looks like this:

[image: after]

The reason for the use of `float` is so that when there are not many icons, the text flows like this:

[image]

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 6px;

}

.icon {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.entry {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="content">

    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">

    <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    <div class="entry">Quisque eleifend viverra risus, nec maximus nisi vestibulum eu</div>
    <div class="entry">Mauris in libero lacus</div>

  </div>  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just smack a `overflow: clip` on your `.content` along with the sexy `overflow-clip-margin: content-box`.

Note on `overflow-clip-margin`: [Safari doesn't support it (yet).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-clip-margin#browser_compatibility) *Quick edit:* [Firefox has some issues with](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661582)  `overflow-clip-margin`'s `visual-box` property too. My bad!

Without it, the images are still clipped but without caring about your `.content` `padding`. Shouldn't be an issue if your text isn't actually behind a `cyan` `background-color`; it's hard to tell on a white background.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: clip;
  overflow-clip-margin: content-box;
}

.icon {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.entry {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="content">

    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">

    <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    <div class="entry">Quisque eleifend viverra risus, nec maximus nisi vestibulum eu</div>
    <div class="entry">Mauris in libero lacus</div>

  </div>  
  
</div>
```

Comment: I can work around the `overflow-clip-margin` issue by putting padding and background color on the parent instead of the content. Thanks!!

Comment: Btw, I've posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74894999/why-does-overflowclip-cause-a-parent-to-have-extra-height

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 8px solid cyan; /* same color */
}

.icons,
.entries {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.icons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
}

.entries {
    margin-left: 56px; /* icon width '38' +  icon left '8' and right '8' distance */
}

.icon {
    background-color: lightpink;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.entry {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

    <div class="content">

      <div class="icons">
        <img class="icon">
        <img class="icon">
        <img class="icon">
        <img class="icon">
      </div>

      <div class="entries">
        <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="entry">Quisque eleifend viverra risus, nec maximus nisi vestibulum eu</div>
        <div class="entry">Mauris in libero lacus</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this approach does not allow the text to flow around the icons when there is only one icon