# Why does overflow:clip result in the correct child height, but an incorrect parent height?

Tags: css, overflow, clip

In the snippet below, why does the `#parent` element have an offsetHeight that is so much taller than the `#content` element?

I am trying to eliminate the red area that is displayed. Is `overflow:clip` broken?

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight)
console.log(document.getElementById('parent').offsetHeight)
```

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: clip;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 38px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, `overflow:clip` isn't broken. It's a paint-time operation, so it doesn't affect layout, So any ancestor which contains its floats will have the same problem, Unfortunately, I don't know any way to resolve this.

Comment: Do you need it to actually float (ie are there situations in which the text would need to float round the bottom of the left element?) I am not quite grasping what the need is here and wonder if a grid would suffice.

Comment: @AHaworth the use case is that I have a set of headlines and thumbnail images, as fully described in my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74881592/how-to-clip-floated-content - is there another approach that I could take to achieve that result, other than float and overflow:clip? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @Alohci I've also noticed that the problem goes away if there is no direct or indirect parent that has position:absolute, which I'm finding hard to understand (in my snippet, it works fine if there is no `position:absolute` on `#parent`) Unfortunately, I need a position:absolute at some point higher up in the DOM tree.

Comment: It's not specifically `position:absolute` that's that problem. Any ancestor that establishes a Block Formatting Context, such as using `display:flow-root` or `overflow:auto` will have the same problem. In your specific case, you could remove the red area by setting the #parent height to 0, and letting the #content overflow that, but I doubt that's a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You directed me here from [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74881592/how-to-clip-floated-content/), and was about to answer but then I read the comments and I can see the answer was already given by Alohci; you need to set a `height` (0) on `#parent`.

However, and this why I included your previous question, that answer might not suffice if you either want to keep the `padding` intact on your `#content` or if you need `#parent` to be its height of its children.

The most flexible solution to have both those things, is using JS to set the `max-height` of `#left` that of the `height` of `#right`. Also gives you the option to get rid of using `overflow:clip` altogether.

```js
document.getElementById('left').style.maxHeight = document.getElementById('right').clientHeight + 'px';
```

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 6px;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 38px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

( Or if you end up needing to use the `height` of `#content` instead, use:

```
const content = document.getElementById('content');
document.getElementById('left').style.maxHeight = (content.offsetHeight - (parseInt(getComputedStyle(content).padding, 10) * 2)) + 'px';
```

)

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted because I appreciate the effort. However, although my snippet sets a specific width on #parent, I was looking for a solution that would work when the page is resized, which would cause the parent width to change. This would affect the clientHeight of the headline text due to word wrapping. The approach in your answer would require javascript to continually monitor for changes in page width, in order to re-apply the maxHeight

Comment: @AndrewParks You likely have your reasons to not want this; but you could always add a resize listener: `window.addEventListener('resize', function() {   });`. If you're worried that it will fire too often, you can always throttle or debounce the function.